# Is it possible to sort by votes in Trello?

Tags: trello

I'd like to set a list, or an entire board, such that all its cards will always be sorted by vote count.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see this card, which has just been moved back to the Trello development board.

https://trello.com/card/sorting-a-list-by-vote-date-label-alphabetically-etc/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/486

> Card order within a list is meaningful. When you change the order of
>   cards in a list, it means something and is reported in a notification.
>   This presents special challenges for the design of any sorting
>   functionality we might consider.
>
> When you sort, who sees it? You or everyone? Is it reported to
>   everyone? What if you inadvertently sort and destroy a list order that
>   was meaningful? Do we need to offer recovery/undo options?
>
> If sorting is just for finding cards, do we offer the ability to sort
>   only for your current view of the interface? How do we reflect that to
>   you so that you don't think you've re-sorted for everyone? What
>   happens if someone changes the order of a list while you have it
>   sorted?
>
> We would need to support sorting temporarily, for viewing, in which
>   case you wouldn't be able to reorder the cards, and everyone else
>   would see the current order, and "solidifying" that sort, which would
>   be reported ("Rich Armstrong reordered the Ideas list by Votes.")
>
> There's clear value in being able to find things in lists, but sorting
>   can be really problematic.
>
> For the foreseeable future, we're likely to focus on improving
>   filtering before tackling any sorting.

Answer (score 2):

No this is currently not possible.

I suggest sending a feature suggestion to their email : `support@trello.com`

Answer (score 0):

While building this feature as native is in debate (changing the order of cards in a list changes the meaning), you can use the [Ultimello extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ultimello-the-features-pa/hahbfgjfimnmogoinnenhheepfcphnmm) in Google Chrome.