# Is there a way to filter by the number of votes on a card?

Tags: trello

I'd like to be able to show all cards that have more than 5 votes.  Alternatively, show all cards that have less than 2 votes, etc.

Is this possible in Trello?

Comment: Related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27123/is-it-possible-to-sort-by-votes-in-trello?rq=1

Comment: What would also be very useful is to filter to see only the cards you have voted for.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not currently possible